# Retain ordering from IN subquery

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

this should be an easy one, but I can't seem to get mysql to play ball.

I'm trying to build a list of projects that a user most recently voted for, to be used on that users profile page.

I have table of votes, containing uid(INT), project(INT), timestamp(INT)

And a table of projects whose id field matches the project field in the votes table.

My initial query was

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id IN(SELECT project FROM votes WHERE uid=x ORDER BY timestamp DESC);
```

This gives a correct list, but the ordering is messed up. I also realised that I had forgotten to add DISTINCT project to the subquery, but for some reason it was giving distinct projects anyway.

```
SELECT project FROM votes WHERE uid=x ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

On its own gives the correct ordering as expected, but as soon as I query from that, the ordering is discarded.

I must not understand how nested statements work, could someone help, and also explain why the DISTINCT keyword is not necessary to get distinct project ids from the votes table!?

**An example as requested;**

The votes table contains individual votes, so if a user votes for a project three times, it might look like this;

```
uid     project    timestamp
34      9          10984
34      9          11093
34      9          11309
```

If that user (34 in the example) then voted for a different project, the votes table would now look like;

```
uid     project    timestamp
34      9          10984
34      9          11093
34      9          11309
34      21         12612
```

The indicies 9 and 21 are then used to query the projects table. So for example the projects table might contain;

```
id     name           description
9      Project A      This is project A.
21     Project B      This is project B.
```

What I want is the list of projects that the user most recently voted for. So in this case I want to grab projects 21 and 9 from the projects table in that order, 21 then 9 and on into projects that the user voted for further into the past.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the desired output? I am having a hard time following this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a join here instead of a subquery.

```
SELECT p.*
    FROM projects p
        INNER JOIN votes v
            ON p.id = v.project
    WHERE v.uid = x
    ORDER BY v.timestamp DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

try with `ORDER BY FIELD` - something like:

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id IN(SELECT project FROM votes WHERE uid=x ORDER BY timestamp DESC) ORDER BY FIELD(id, (SELECT project FROM votes WHERE uid=x ORDER BY timestamp DESC) );
```

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` is not necessary because even though the `IN()` subquery may return duplicates, the outer query is  merely looking for matching values among those, not 1:1 relationships. This is different than `JOIN` behavior, where you would likely end up with duplicate rows.

It's similar to saying you have an array `[1,2,2,4,5,5]` and asking which of the values from a different array `[1,2,5,6]` occur *anywhere* in the first array.  The answer is always `[1,2,5]`. Hopefully this illustration isn't more confusing. I'll edit it as I think of ways to improve it.

Previous answers supply the correct `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I understand thank you for explaining, I have used mysql for years and have managed to avoid joins completely so far. Perhaps I should learn how they work!

Comment: @lynks Absolutely you should learn `JOIN`s. Depending on table size, a `JOIN` can be orders of magnitude faster than an `IN()` subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite this as a join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT projects.* FROM projects 
   JOIN votes ON projects.id = votes.project             
   ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```